# Optimal Directed Dijkstra search in Python

Tags: python, algorithm, performance, dijkstra, conventions

I've played around writing my own heap and trying out the directed Dijkstra's algorithm using a heap to store the distances.

I've cross-checked the answers with Bellman-Ford (and also on paper) so I'm confident it runs correctly, however it seems to be too slow for my liking. I've also made my own Graph class to hold the value of vertices/the length/head/tail of edges

```
def dijkstra(G,root):
    ###Initialize values
    root.value=0
    h=heap.Heap(root)
    for v in G.vertices:
        if v==root:
            continue
        v.value=float('inf')
        h.insert(v)
    while len(h.nodes)>1:
        m=h.extractmin()
        ##Only works for directed graphs 
        for E in m.edges:
            if (E.v in h.nodes) and E.v.value>m.value+E.d:
            #If head of the min vrtx is in the heap
                E.v.value=m.value+E.d
                h.check_parent(h.nodes.index(E.v)) #percolate up
```

On an input of 50k edges and 1k nodes, it takes >30sec to complete. Is this a reasonable time to expect with python? Assuming that the algorithm is correct, would my heap be the limiting factor?

(Also I know that I'm directly modifying/accessing members of the class, ie v.value=... , is that bad practice? I haven't specifically declared them private)

Thanks for the input!

Comment: If this code actually works, this might be better suited to [code-review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/) but make sure you read their policy first

Comment: You can compare performance with the  [python-graph](https://github.com/pmatiello/python-graph) library

Answer (score 0):

> Is this a reasonable time to expect with python?

Unable to answer this without knowing your system specifications. Try comparing against a pre-built data structure e.g. https://docs.python.org/2/library/heapq.html

> would my heap be the limiting factor?

Yes.

> is that bad practice?

This question is a bit out of place. You are asking about OO at the same time as asking about Algorithms.

Finally, ensure that your heap implementation can achieve the following in `O(1)` instead of `O(n)`:

```
if (E.v in h.nodes)
```

You don't have to support the operation in your heap, btw. You can simply have another Boolean property for the vertices and set `v.inHeap = True` when it's added to the heap, and set it to `False` when it is extracted from the heap.